# What "папа и баба" would translate into Russian graphemes?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

This is part of the phonetics class but I can not find any information about this in the book, the hand outs or on any other electronic resource. It is somewhat narrow field (question). I am curious what "папа и баба" would translate into Russian graphemes?

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by "grapheme"? I suppose that the answer is "no difference at all".

Comment: GRAPHEMES  are individual letters and groups of letters that represent single phonemes, like the “s” and the “oo” in “spoon”. http://www.readingdoctor.com.au/phonemes-graphemes-letters-word-burger/

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same what you wrote.

Comment: You see, Russian writing is much more easy, than English. My answer is not 100% accurate (there are lots of exceptions), but it's good enough for the beginners. Here is the rule: no graphemes! You see the letter, you read the sound. There are significant differences only for consonants preceding letters "е, ё, и, ь, ъ, ю, я".

Comment: @ева: I don't think the authors of that site understand well what grapheme is. A grapheme, by definition, is the smallest unit of a writing system, which "oo" is not for English. They don't have to represent a single phoneme (or any number of phonemes at all). What they call a grapheme, is in fact a multigraph: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph_(orthography)

Answer (score 2):

*Папа и баба* translate into a total of 11 graphemes (of which 5 are distinct: *п, а, и, б*, space) in modern Russian writing, *П* and *п* being allographs of the same grapheme.

If we would have used a Church Slavonic written rendition of the same phrase:

> Па́па и҆ ба́ба

,  that would have been a total of 14 graphemes, 7 distinct: *п, а, и, б*, space, acute accent, psili.

Answer (score 1):

папа and баба translate in graphemes as папа and баба. There ara no graphemes --or if you want, the words are the graphemes. For the phonetics is as complicated languages which use them (incidentally English is the only language I know, that presents graphemes. German, French, Spanish, Italian, etc. don't).

If Russian phonetics is unfamiliar to you, it might then be helpful to consider lerning [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) instead. In particular, if your aim is to learn another language after/together with Russian.

Comment: The question was a two part question. IPA and Cyrillic grapheme. I have managed the IPA part easily. I have major difficulty understanding why someone asks something about something that is hardly documented but I guess that is how things are when you hire people that are no real teachers. The graphemes are not even covered in her own hand outs.

Comment: @ева If it was a two-part question, you should make that explicit in the body of the question. There, IPA is not mentioned.  Graphemes are useless. Even in English, they are the worst alternative.